# Run system command with no output

Tags: python-2.7

I'm running a `wget` in Python via `os.system`.

Is there anyways to hide the output?  I tried

```
> /dev/null
```

and tried running the command with a `$` in front of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python - how to execute system command with no output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500477/in-python-how-to-execute-system-command-with-no-output)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module instead.

Using `subprocess.call` (which is a helper function for some more advanced subprocess features), you can redirect stdout and stderr to file objects. If you open `/dev/null` (the os module has `os.devnull` which is a platform-independant path of the null device that can help), you can hand it to subprocess.call and suppress all output

```
import os
import subprocess

devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
subprocess.call([...], stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
```