# Run a terminal command at python without show the result

Tags: python, terminal

Hi I'm working with a python script, and I need to run some terminal commands but I dont want to see the result of them. I'm using this code:

```
comando = ('fping -c1 -g 192.168.1.0/24')
valor = os.system((comando))
comando = ('arp -n > /home/edgar/Documentos/wips/arp')
valor = os.system((comando))
```

The terminal show me the list of the fping command.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: You should be using subprocess module here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python - how to execute system command with no output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500477/in-python-how-to-execute-system-command-with-no-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would avoid using `os.system` in favor of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596911/python-os-system-without-the-output) but given your code you could redirect the stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`:

```
comando = ('fpin -c1 -g 192.168.1.0/24 > /dev/null 2>&1')
valor = os.system(comando)
```

Comment: glad to hear. please accept this as the answer if it worked.